# determine MDP from seen transitions

Tags: artificial-intelligence, policy, reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

The following transitions has been seen in a markov decision process. try to determine it

```
 R  A  S′ S

 0  U  C  B
-1  L  E  C
 0  D  C  A
-1  R  E  C
 0  D  C  A
+1  R  D  C
 0  U  C  B
+1  R  D  C
```

I need to find the states, transitions, rewards and probability of transitions.
I've solved all but the probabilities and I don't know how to compute them
If anyone can help, I just need to know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For state `B`, action `U` always results in new state `C`. So, `P(C|B,U)=1` (you might also argue that `P(C|B)=1`). `P(D|C,R)=2/3` since in two out of three cases action `R` in state `C` has resulted in `D`.